# Why doesn't the balance point change in this case?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity

[image]

What happens to the balance point when the switch S is closed. The answer given is that it doesn't change. But I don't understand why ? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

When the galvanometer is placed at the balance point, no current will flow in the circuit. This means that there will be no potential drop across the resistor. This means that we can treat the section from E<sub>2</sub> to the galvanometer as a piece of ordinary wire without any resistance, so the status of the switch does not matter.